# Add custom metadata records to unlocked package

Tags: unlocked-package, custom-metadata

Like the question says. I'm trying to find a way to add custom metadata records to an unlocked package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just retrieve the custom metadata object, and it will include the records as well.

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomMetadata
```

The records will be stored in same folder with the name used as part of the file:

```
customMetadata/METADATATYPE.RECORDNAME.md-meta.xml
```

Comment: I tried running that CLI command but it just retrieved the metadata, not the record.

Comment: Scratch that (get it?), I was doing it wrong! It worked, thanks a lot @sfdcfox!

Comment: @DiegoMoreno You're welcome!